# Where does notification observers fit in the VIPER pattern?

Tags: ios, swift, viper-architecture

I am changing my project to VIPER pattern.

I got a lot of observers for my main view. I don't find where should I place my observers in VIPER .

Because i don't want to place my observer in view . 
Previously I had separate class for observers and when there use to be notification , I use to update to main view.

But in new VIPER i don't know where is best place.

Should I make new VIPER-N  ? N for notification observations .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guys if you are confused .
Then put the observers in interactor.

p.s : don't get confused 
and then transfer the data received in integrator to presenter to view .

:) :)

Happy viper.